# Cannot receive data while VPN is connected on separate machine

Tags: networking, vpn, tcp

I have three linux machines, one at work (desktop 'D') and two at home (laptop 'L', raspberry pi 'R'). I want to transmit data from my work machine to one at home. The data transmission in question is only ever outbound from work.

1. I can access the desktop D from L, when I connect to my work VPN.
2. When the VPN is connected, and I am remotely logged into the desktop, **I cannot send any data from D -> R.** The VPN connects L <-> D.
3. when I disconnect the VPN, connections from D -> R work. (e.g. if I set a sleep command before trying to open a connection, and in that time, disconnect the VPN)

This situation is rather annoying as I cannot debug interactively. And what I find most strange is that the VPN connection is not between the machines that are communicating!

I have admin rights on the 3 machines. I have some control over the local router, including port forwarding. I have no control over the servers/VPN frontend etc at work.

---

Which machine is badly configured? Is it normal for VPNs to have side effects to other machines on the same network? What am I doing wrong?

[image: nodes in the problem]

Comment: can you provided us with an edited routing table of **D** when VPN is ON and when VPN is OFF ? maybe along with a `traeroute -p 1234 123.1.2.3` from D in both state of VPN (ON/OFF) ?

Comment: this is embarrassing, after struggling with this for 4 days before asking, the problem has now disappeared. I did a system upgrade without thinking about it, and the error no longer manifests.  The upgrade included `networkd-dispatcher` and a bunch of samba packages that seem unrelated. I'm not sure the new info will help since the problem is gone.

Comment: no need to be embarraced, the most important thing is that problem is solved. However we should now close question as "unreproductible"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your laptop tries to route all traffic through VPN. If you are using GUI to set up the VPN to there should be an option similar to `Use this connection only for resources on network` on Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The only option I have is "Allow LAN access when using VPN", but it is already selected. 
As I commented on the question it seems that an old package on my laptop could have caused the problem - but I'm not going to install the old ones just to check since I have a working network finally!